# Detecting swipe gesture for a gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement some functionality when an user swipes on the grid view of my screen. I tried using a SimpleOnGestureListener as follows:

```
    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {                      
                Log.w(null,"Right to Left swipe detected");

                return true;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {                         
                Log.w(null,"Left to Right swipe detected");

                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However am not able to detect the motion events . I tried debugging and saw that event e1 is passed as null . Can someone help?

Comment: Somewhere i read that you can't detect the swipe events on a grid view . I have made a custom calendar which is a gridview . What i want to achieve is the month to change on swiping. Is there any way i can detect swipe events on the gridview?